# How do I print from a Python 2.7 script invoked from Bash within PyCharm?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, output, pycharm

For example if I have a python script `test.py` containing

```
import time

print 'foo'
time.sleep(5)

print 'bar'
time.sleep(5)
```

and a shell script `run_test.sh` containing

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

python test.py
```

then running the latter (using the Run menu item for example) from within PyCharm (2016.1) prints no output until the entire script has completed (after about 10 seconds).

Is there a way to print output as my shell script runs?

Comment: Does `print('foo', flush=True)` help?

Comment: What PyCharm version? I can't reproduce this at all.

Comment: Actually... try going to Run, then Edit Configurations. Under Environment Variables, set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: No: `TypeError: 'flush' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: ah, Python 2, missed that, sorry. `import sys` at the top, then `sys.stdout.flush()` after each print statement.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: but that then does raise the question: why are you putting `(...)` parenheses around the strings to print? `print` is a statement, not a function, in Python 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That works. Is there a way to make tat apply to all `print` statements in a script?

Comment: @Will: `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` is already set.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The `(...)` are out of habit. I usually import from future.

Comment: @Will: PyCharm 2016.1.

Comment: Add `export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` to the shell script?

Comment: @Will: Yep, that also works. Either that or `-u` does the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to explicitly flush the buffer:

```
import sys

print 'foo'
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(5)

print 'bar'
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(5)
```

See [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering) for Python 2 solutions that auto-flush after every print.

In your case, since you control the bash file that runs Python, just add `-u` or set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`:

```sh
python -u test.py
```

or

```sh
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 python test.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to [@MartijnPieters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) with regard to PyCharm:

In PyCharm, set the run configuration for the shell script under **Run**->**Edit Configurations**, like so:

[image]

Note the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`.

You may have to first add a Bash run configuration under the **Defaults** menu on the left.